# JButton within JTable Icon/Animation Changing When Pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, tablecellrenderer

I don't really know how to explain this in words. So I have a JTable with a JButton Column. I have set an icon for this button but when I press or hold the button, it changes into the image you see below.

[image]

How can I disable this effect? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
  renderButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
  renderButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ButtonColumn.class
                .getResource("/com/graphics/clear_left.png")));
  renderButton.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(ButtonColumn.class
                .getResource("/com/graphics/clear_left.png")));
  renderButton.setRolloverSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ButtonColumn.class
                .getResource("/com/graphics/clear_left.png")));
  renderButton.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(ButtonColumn.class
                .getResource("/com/graphics/clear_left.png")));
```

Comment: Which editor you use for the column?

Comment: uh.. I think an AbstractCellEditor that implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor, ActionListener, MouseListener

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable in local variable, for simple higlighting (as you want to do) read Oracle tutorial - How to use tables, part about JToolTip

Comment: your JSpinner (as rendering component) missing some kind of selection, isn't completed,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your code I think you use Rob Camick's [ButtonColumn](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) to get the buttons column decoration. That class implements both [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and [TableCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) interfaces to provide a `JButton` as renderer and editor for the cells in the column you specify, in your case the last one.

What you did is to customize the renderer button to show the icon you want but now you have to customize the editor button as well to override the default button's look.

In both cases I wouldn't modify the [source code](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ButtonColumn.java) directly but override both `getTableCellXxxComponent(...)` methods instead, just like any other custom renderer/editor. Something like this will make it:

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

Action action = new AbstractAction() {...};

ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table, action, 5) {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JButton button = (JButton)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        // Customize the icon and whatever you want here
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        JButton button = (JButton)super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        // Customize the icon and whatever you want here
        return button;
    }
};
```

#### Notes

Always include a link to non-standard libraries or classes. Otherwise people won't be a able to help you with classes they are not familiar with.

As @mKorbel pointed out, the `JSpinner` used to render the 5th column isn't complete: the selection background color should be applied if the cell is selected (see the first row).

Comment: Holy Cow! Yes you got exactly what I did without much explanation on my part. This seems like the perfect solution. Ill try it tomorrow at work. Thanks for a very detailed answer. Ill up and choose this after i test.

Comment: You are welcome :) Give it a try and share your feedback. Nice design BTW. @mfrancisp

Answer (score 0):

I can't use ButtonColumn as well and I have found another way to do the job: add a `mouseListener` to the `jTable` and return clicked cell by its position.

```
Rectangle[] cells;
for(int i=0;i<row;i++){cells[i] = Table_Skill.getCellRect(i, 7, false);}

MouseListener ml = new MouseListener(){
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        Point point_clicked = new Point(e.getX(),e.getY());
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                if(cells[i].contains(point_clicked))
                {
                //some action like deleting the row
                break;
                }
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
};
Table_Skill.addMouseListener(ml);
```